# Display value of column header with value from bean

Tags: jsf

Is there a way to display the name of the header of a column in the h:dataTable by fetching the value from the bean:

Instead of this:

```
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="NAME" />
</f:facet>
```

I want this:

```
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="#{column.columnText}" />
</f:facet>
```

Currently with the second block of code the value is displayed as blank

Comment: What do you see with `<f:facet name="header">#{column.columnText}</f:facet>`? Does `column.columnText` really have a value? It sounds  as if it is empty in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible as you described it.

The code you showed is correct and should work. You can also do it like this:

```
<f:facet name="header">
#{column.columnText}
</f:facet>
```

You have to make sure you have a bean named `column` which has a field named `ColumnText`. If it is not working there is something wrong with your bean or the field is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try as per your suggestion also.